# Replace text with image in pdf using itext

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to replace text in an existing PDF with image. Can this be done using itext?

Comment: *Can this be done using itext?* Yes. But not out of the box. My first idea would be to copy the PDF parsing mechanism (cf. the parser package) and change it to allow for removing (part of) the current text piece. Adding an image at the position is the easiest part.

Comment: I have a textfield in pdf named "T1" suppose and I have an image "img1.jpg". Now I have to place img1.jpg inside the textfield T1. Cany anybody help me with this code?

Comment: So you don't want to replace *text* (in the page content) but instead a *text field*! That is easier.

Comment: I want to place the image inside the textfield/textbox. But how?

Comment: [Here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=156) is an iText example which creates a new `PushbuttonField` from an existing field and sets its icon (which can be an arbitrary image). Unfortunately the `AcroFields` methods `getNewPushbuttonFromField` and `replacePushbuttonField` used in the sample expect the original field to also be a button field. Thus, you will have to generalize these methods for your use case.